# PHP not updating select boxes correctly

Tags: php

Here is another one. Twice in the same day. I'm trying to set up 4 select boxes that shows a option selected based the values in Target1-4 if they are equal to the value of enSlot.

```
echo "<select id='target".$row['paSlot']."' size='1' style='width:90px;'>";
$query = "SELECT * FROM enemy WHERE enChar = ".$_SESSION['chNum']." ORDER BY enSlot";
$result1 = mysql_query($query, $_SESSION['connect']) or die('Error 150: '.mysql_error());
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $s = "";
    if ($_GET['Target1'] == $row1['enSlot']) {
            $s = "selected='selected'";
    }
    if ($_GET['Target2'] == $row1['enSlot']) {
            $s = "selected='selected'";
    }
    if ($_GET['Target3'] == $row1['enSlot']) {
            $s = "selected='selected'";
    }
    if ($_GET['Target4'] == $row1['enSlot']) {
            $s = "selected='selected'";
    }
    echo "<option value=".$row1['enSlot']." ".$s.">".$row1['enSlot'].". ".$row1['enRace'];
}
echo "</select>";
```

I run it with this:

Target1 = 1, Target2 = 2, Target3 = 3, Target4 = 4
Enemy has 4 records, enSlot = 1 - 4

When it executes I get all 4 select boxes show the last value of Target4 being selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your logic no matter which condition evaluates the value of $s always will be selected=selected... You may try this:

```
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    foreach( $_GET[] as $target ) {
        if( $target == $row1['enSlot'] ) {
            echo "<option value=".$row1['enSlot']." selected=selected>".$row1['enSlot'].". ".$row1['enRace']."</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value=".$row1['enSlot'].">".$row1['enSlot'].". ".$row1['enRace']."</option>";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<option value=".$row1['enSlot']." ".$s.">".$row1['enSlot'].". ".$row1['enRace'];
```

i see missing `</option>`

Comment: Thanks, sloppy programming, but that didn't solve the problem.